# How to Disable auto id attributes in Heading tag?

Tags: block-editor, tags, html, editor, automation

I don’t know why but WP is automatically adding id attributes to h2 tags. I am not supplying any id or class attribute and I don’t need it. Also, it’s adding `type="1"` to `<ol>` tag that’s not needed in my case.

You can see it on this page:
https://idioms.a2hosted.com/2022/02/15/its-not-brain-surgery/

Please help, how to stop it?

I need this:

`<h2>Meaning</h2>`

`<h2>Example Sentences</h2>`

`<h2>Origin</h2>`

**This is what WP doing with it.**

`<h2 id="meaning">Meaning</h2>`

`<h2 id="example-sentences">Example Sentences</h2>`

`<h2 id="origin">Origin</h2>`